# Wrapping WPF command in exception manager Process<T>() using EnterpriseLibrary

Tags: wpf, exception, command, enterprise-library

I would like to change the way i handling exception using WPF command

a simple command in view:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
  <dxr:RibbonPageGroup x:Uid="dxr:RibbonPageGroup_1" Caption="Edit">
       <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Uid="dxb:BarButtonItem_1" Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Save_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Save_16x16.png}"/>
  </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
<!-->
```

a simple command method in view model will looks like:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
              [Command ="SaveCommand"]
              public virtual void Save()
              {
                try
                {
                //do stuff
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This is simple exception");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                        IConfigurationSource config = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
                        ExceptionPolicyFactory factory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(config);
                        Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);

                        ExceptionManager exceptionManager = factory.CreateManager();

                        exceptionManager.HandleException(ex, "Policy");
                }   
              } 
<!-->
```

Every time i'm adding new command i need to copy and paste the same code, with make a source code redudant and ugly.

So i would to change way of exception handling to more elegant way using

```
<!-- language: c# -->
         exceptionManager.Process(() => { Save(); }, "Policy");
<!-->
```

but here is the problem this won't work:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
             [Command ="SaveCommand"]
             public virtual void Save()
             {
                        IConfigurationSource config = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
                        ExceptionPolicyFactory factory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(config);
                        Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);

                        ExceptionManager exceptionManager = factory.CreateManager();
                        exceptionManager.Process(() => { Save(); }, "Policy");
             }
<!-->
```

because i'm already in Save() method scope - i hope you know what i mean.

the optimal solution would be exception handling using mechanic similar like in PostSharp - using reflection and decorate Save() method with an attribute

```
<!-- language: c# -->
    [FormatedException(Policy = "Policy")]
    public virtual void Save()
    {
    }
<!-->
```

What do you guys think? 
I would like to know your opinions, maybe you find better solution. Maybe is there way to wrap command BEFORE execute it in view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the syntax a little to put all statements you want run in your generic exception handler:

```
[Command ="SaveCommand"]
public virtual void Save()
{
    exceptionManager.Process(() => 
    {
        IConfigurationSource config = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
        ExceptionPolicyFactory factory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(config);
        Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);
        ExceptionManager exceptionManager = factory.CreateManager();
     }, 
     "Policy");
}
```

Or, you could break this up into two functions

```
[Command ="SaveCommand"]
public virtual void TrySave()
{
    exceptionManager.Process(() => 
    {
        Save();
     }, 
     "Policy");
}

public virtual void Save()
{
    IConfigurationSource config = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
    ExceptionPolicyFactory factory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(config);
    Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);
    ExceptionManager exceptionManager = factory.CreateManager();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting these Command attributes from? Do you have a link to a learning resource?

Comment: I copied the command attributes part from the original question.  I only addressed the syntax of the lambda expression.

Comment: Ah, I see, I'd be interested in seeing how the OP is implementing this. Any help @Cowa?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry that I do not answer. I'm using devexpress MVVM library here is the link: https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExpress.Mvvm.Free its free and provides a pretty decent way to implement MVVM patern in projects.